# Autoware NDT_Matching not matching

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently attempting to run Autoware’s ndt_matching process with little success. I have gotten the ndt_matching to work in the ROSBAG Demo provided on the gitlab with the suggested/preset settings and with changing it from starting with GNSS to starting at an initial position of [0,0,0,0,0,0] and changing the type of matching (pcl_generic, pcl_anh, and pcl_openmp).

So far I have built a few .pcd map files with the ndt_mapping process and have attempted to use that to localize off of using a similar process to what is described in the example launch files:

- my_mapping.launch with tf_launch (with the world to map transform set to 0,0,0 instead of the default values in the usual tf.launch) and the points_map_loader node with the .pcd file I created previously.
- my_sensing.launch with a driver for a 64-plane Ouster LiDAR that outputs a topic /os1_cloud_node/points in PointCloud2 format and a driver for a Microstrain IMU that outputs /gps/fix and translates that into the /fix topic required by ndt_matching (of msg type NavSatFix)
- my_localization.launch:
- setup_tf.launch of base_link to os1_lidar
- vehicle_model.launch that loads the urdf file for my vehicle and starts the joint_state_publisher and robot_state_publisher nodes
- points_downsample.launch where it looks at the /os1_cloud_node/points topic (remaped from the /points_raw topic) for point values and I have tried multiple values for the voxel_grid_filter
- fix2tfpose.launch

I then go in manually to add the ndt_matching from the Runtime Manager (and have started also using ndt_matching_monitor from there as well).

Since the ndt_mapping process does not seem to include gnss data from the bag file, I initialize the position with [0,0,0,0,0,0]. Predict Pose is ON. I have increased and decreased the following values individually and in combination: Error Threshold, Resolution, Step Size, Transformation Epsilon, and Maximum Iterations for three of the four Method Types (pcl_generic, pcl_anh, and pcl_openmp) {did not use the pcl_anh_gpu due to memory errors on my computer related to the gpu}
I am not using Odometry nor IMU but I do have Get Height checked because that was what the original ndt_matching had as its option on the original my_localization.launch. I have started with the preset settings (the ones that are used and work on the ROSBAG demo) of Error Threshold=1, Resolution=1, Step Size=0.1, Transformation Epsilon=0.01, and Maximum Iterations=30, but again have increased/decreased those values and tested the results.

I have created 3 .pcd maps: two of the area surrounding my building, with a different [0,0,0] for both, and one inside my lab.
Initially, when using the outside maps, I was having the problem (mostly with pcl_openmp) of the ndt_matching initially checking around the start point but then eventually zooming off the map unable to recover. However, now even when I run the map inside my lab and the vehicle has not moved from the position where the map was recorded, the ndt_matching still fails, or rather fails successfully.

What I mean by that: the ndt_matching_monitor reports success despite the ndt_matching point cloud not being correctly matched to the pcd map (visualized in Rviz). I tried it first with the initial position being in the same orientation as the map, and also have it rotated 90deg and 180deg, all three reporting NDT OK despite that not being the case. (voxel grid size 0.5 for the /filtered_points) [these photos are in the following google drive link)

After messing with the ROSBAG demo some more I figured it might be that the vehicle needed to move so that the input point cloud would change and make the ndt_matching realize it was incorrect, but after taking it outside again with the outside maps, this was not the case as far as I could tell.

I have attached the two outside map I created, and their associated bag file. The bag files only contains the /fix topic and the /os1_cloud_node/points topic because those were the only topics in the bag file for the ROSBAG demo, along with /tf and /tf_static.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VjH0g4-50EUmx9i58qeGPvkZUqnXSCGq?usp=sharing

My current specs are:
Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel 5.0
ROS Melodic
Autoware 1.12
Installation Method: Docker

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am lost and new to most of this. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328320/autoware-ndt_matching-not-matching/) by [bcopenha](https://answers.ros.org/users/44041/bcopenha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try as follows.

1. Play rosbag(slam_topics_2019-07-01-10-02-59.bag) and pause immediately.
2. Execute the following command to fix header.stamp to current ros time.

   ```
    $ rosrun topic_tools relay_field /os1_cloud_node/points /points_raw sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 "header:  
     seq: m.header.seq  
     stamp: now  
     frame_id: m.header.frame_id  
     height: m.height  
    width: m.width  
    fields:  
    - {name: "x", offset: 0, datatype: 7, count: 1}  
    - {name: "y", offset: 4, datatype: 7, count: 1}  
    - {name: "z", offset: 8, datatype: 7, count: 1}  
    - {name: "intensity", offset: 16, datatype: 7, count: 1}  
    - {name: "t", offset: 20, datatype: 6, count: 1}  
    - {name: "reflectivity", offset: 24, datatype: 4, count: 1}  
    - {name: "ring", offset: 26, datatype: 2, count: 1}  
    - {name: "noise", offset: 28, datatype: 4, count: 1}  
    - {name: "range", offset: 32, datatype: 6, count: 1}  
    is_bigendian: m.is_bigendian  
    point_step: m.point_step  
    row_step: m.row_step  
    data: m.data  
    is_dense: m.is_dense"
   ```
3. Set BaseLink to Localizer(params is [0.465, 0, 1.945, 3.142, 0, 0])
4. Publish Point Cloud Map(autoware-190703-2.pcd)
5. Publish TF(autoware/ros/src/.config/tf/tf_local.launch)
6. Launch voxel_grid_filter(config: "Points Topic" is "/points_raw")
7. Launch ndt_matching(config: "Initial Pos" is [-5.68, 59.18, -5.775, -0.141, 0.004, 0.703])
8. Restart rosbag.

---

Originally posted by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) with karma: 231 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bcopenha](https://answers.ros.org/users/44041/bcopenha/) on 2019-07-12**:
Yamato,

Thank you for your reply!

The above works, with a slight modification: Step 2 should not have the indent before `height: m.height` and I also put the entire part in green into single quotes ( ' ) instead of double as to not interfere with the naming of the fields.

My follow-up question is how did you get the values for the Initial Pos for Step 7? This seems to have been the source of my issue and I am wondering what determined them. Thank you again!

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-07-15**:
Thank you for your comment on the correction.
The method of determining the value of Initial Pos used the 2D Pose Estimate of Rviz and searched the position which can be matched manually.
And the output value of the following command was made Initial Pose.

`$ rosrun tf tf_echo world base_link`

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2019-09-20**:
@Yamato

Hello,

I have been tested Autoware localization (lidar localizer using ndt_matching) with Velodyne (16, 32 and 64) model sensors and Ouster 64 channel sensor. With all the sensor localizer working good. But with the Hesai Pandar64 channel lidar getting an error like this bellow. Above mentioned sensors tested with the same map data and with the frame id modified to "velodyne".

Could you please comment on this, looking forward to hearing from you.

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-09-26**:
@Ajay
Hello,
Please paste the error message.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-09-27**:
@ajay Since this is an unrelated and new issue, please post a new question.

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2019-09-28**:
@Yamato
Thanks for your kind reply.

Error Message :
For frame [velodyne]: No transform to fixed frame [world]. TF error: [Lookup would require extrapolation into the past. Requested time 946655660.000381000 but the earliest data is at time 1568785504.549147331, when looking up transform from frame [velodyne] to frame [world]]

Also commented in the Autoware forum https**://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware/issues/2321**

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-09-30**:
@Ajay It seems that TF has not been converted well, because the sensor time stamp is strange.
Please modify the sensor driver.

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2019-09-30**:
@Yamato Thanks for your reply, I will check the sensor driver and get back to you.